# ¿Por que no puedo crear un array de objetos?

Tags: c++, array, poo

estoy realizando mi clase weapon, pero al la hora de crear un arreglo de objetos el compilador tarda demasiado en instanciar la clase, no se si sere yo o si no lo instancie apropiadamente, pues el resto de mis clases si pueden generar un array de objetos si lo escribo.

```
class weapon
{
    string name;
    string description;
    int sizes;
    string *improved_stat;
    int *increase;

public:
    weapon();
};

weapon::weapon()
{
    name = "empty";
    description = "empty";
    improved_stat = new string[0];
    increase = new int[0];
    sizes = 0;
}
```

cuando intento crear un array objetos de tipo "weapon" el compilador tarda segundos en declararla, ¿por que es esto?

```
int main()
{
    weapon r[4];
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*el compilador tarda segundos en declararla*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
improved_stat = new string[0];
increase = new int[0];
```

no entiendo las razones que te pueden llevar a hacer esto... haces una reserva de 0 elementos, es como ir a comprar leche al super y traerse solo el cartón.

En cualquier caso debes saber lo siguiente:

- Cuando se invoca al operador new con tamaño 0, se reserva memoria para un array sin elementos
- Desreferenciar un puntero de tamaño 0 provoca un comportamiento indefinido

Nuevamente, insisto. Ignoro qué es lo que pretendías inicialmente con esos `new`. Si tu idea era inicializar esos punteros, lo más común, elegante y seguro es usar `nullptr`:

```
improved_stat = nullptr;
increase = nullptr;
```

De esta manera los punteros apuntarán a `null`, a 0, o a la dirección de memoria 0, como prefieras explicarlo.

Comment: Gracias, ese era el problema, yo creia que reservar memoria de un array de tamaño 0 era igual a que usar nullptr,